# Declaring an object of random class in class definition

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

So, I am writing a class in which I need to generate random numbers sampled from a uniform distribution. Since I need to generate random numbers frequently I want to create an object inside the class definition.

Here is the example of what I am trying to accomplish. 
"example.h"

```
class ABC
{
  public:
   ABC();
   /* code goes here */
  private:
   std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device rd;);
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
}
```

"example.cpp"

```
ABC::ABC():ABC::dist(0,12)
{
  /* ABC class constructor */
}
```

The above code doesn't compile. Can anyone help or point out the mistake. Thanks in advance.
Following errors are generated by g++ compiler.

```
src/tsim.cpp: In constructor ‘TrafficSim::TrafficSim(bool, float)’:
src/tsim.cpp:5:71: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
 TrafficSim::TrafficSim(bool render,float time_period):TrafficSim::dist(0,110)
                                                                       ^
src/tsim.cpp:5:71: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
src/tsim.cpp: At global scope:
src/tsim.cpp:5:72: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 TrafficSim::TrafficSim(bool render,float time_period):TrafficSim::dist(0,110)
                                                                        ^
src/tsim.cpp:5:72: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've incorrectly defined your constructor.

In order to define a member initializer list you instead need to define it as

```
ABC::ABC() : dist(0, 12)
{
  /* ABC class constructor */
}
```

A member initializer list works by directly after the function signature putting
    : memberName(constructor operands)
If you want to initialize multiple members you simply comma delimit them.

Comment: There's also an extra (erroneous) semicolon here: `std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device rd;);` [sic]